# SSRS - How do I toggle Group Sort based on a parameter value

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, conditional-statements

I have and expression like this in my group sort:

Not working - Conditional

```
=IIF(Parameters!grouping.Value="CS",Fields!TotRpt.Value,0)
=IIF(Parameters!grouping.Value="CS",Fields!TotRpt.Value,Nothing)
```

Working - Explicit

```
Fields!TotRpt.Value
```

Does anyone know how to get the Sort to toggle based on a parameter value?

Comment: The expression looks like it should work when `CS` is selected, but when any other value is selected it will just be sorted by a constant. How should the sorting work if `CS` is *not* selected? Also, is there any other sorting at the Tablix or Detail row level?

Answer (score 0):

I checked and found Parameters!grouping.Value wasn't passing in "CS" properly when it should have. I fixed it and =IIF(Parameters!grouping.Value="CS",Fields!TotRpt.Value,Nothing) as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

=not Parameters!ParamiterName.Value or =Parameters!ParamiterName.Value